# Values stacked in the same line with layout package

Tags: layout, measure

I'm having a problem with the `layout` package: it shows the grid, but the values are all stacked in the same line.

[image]

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{article}

\usepackage[top=46.5mm,bottom=46.5mm,inner=39mm,outer=39mm, marginparwidth=10mm, marginparsep=4mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{layout}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\lay@value}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr0.351459\dimexpr\csname#2\endcsname\relax\relax mm%
}
\makeatother



\usepackage[en]{metre}
\usepackage{metrix}


\usepackage{alphalph}



\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Kallimachos_SC.ttf, BoldFont=Kallimachos_Bold,ItalicFont=Kallimachos_Italic]{Leptos.ttf}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Leptos.ttf}


\newcommand{\lts}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15 plus 1 minus 1}#1}}

\newcommand{\ltsb}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12 plus 1 minus 1}#1}}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{{\selectlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}#1}}



\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}


\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating} 


\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{rm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{ragged2e} 


\usepackage{hyphenat} 

\usepackage{hanging} 

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabu}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{stackrel}   
\usepackage{amsmath}    

\usepackage{afterpage} 

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[bottom,norule]{footmisc}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
\oldfootnote{\hspace{2mm}#1}}

\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{x}
\input{notes_2}


\makesavenoteenv{tabular} 
\makesavenoteenv{table}

\interfootnotelinepenalty=0 

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.2cm}


\addtolength{\skip\footins}{15pt} 


\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,nocritical,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage[continuousnumberingwithcolumns]{reledpar}

\linenumberLevenifblanktrue

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\columnsposition{c}
\setlength{\beforecolumnseparator}{0.05\textwidth}
\setlength{\aftercolumnseparator}{0.05\textwidth}


\usepackage{parcolumns}

\lineskiplimit=-100pt\relax 

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength\parindent{15pt}


\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15} 

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\@baselinestretch{1} 
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\def\FN@baselinestretch{1} 
\makeatother

\afterpage{\blankpage}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\renewcommand\marginfont{%
    \normalfont\tiny
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

How can I do to fix it? Is it a problem related to something in my preamble?

Comment: It could be related to your class (not shown), the papersize (not shown) how you got the picture (not shown). Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile. If you think that the problem is with your preamble then comment out stuff until it works --- then the problem is caused by something you commented out.

Comment: Thank you Peter Wilson, I commented the single voices in the preamble and I found that \lineskiplimit=-100pt\relax was brokening the output.